# Is microsoft.com not using TLS/SSL?

Tags: tls

On my way to Microsoft to download "security essentials", I noticed that the download page isn't a secure site. Is this legitimately the case, or an indication that I may be compromised in some way? (Some kind of name resolution hijack?)

Comment: Since the executable you download is signed, I think they made it easier for a proxy server to cache rather than go for extra privacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Microsoft.com does indeed run using standard `HTTP` rather than `HTTPS` (TLS/SSL secured). However, their website can be accessed using `HTTPS` if you enter: `https://www.microsoft.com`. This causes the main page to display over a secured connection.

That said, their security essentials page (`http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download`) is not accessible using `HTTPS` and results in a `404 Not Found` error (if your browser even lets you open it).

I do not know why Microsoft would use standard `HTTP` instead of secure `HTTPS`, but it appears that they do. It seems like a poor set-up on their part, but I do not believe this means either you or they are compromised.